Refer to Scala class parameters using a string variable
Say I have this scala class:
    case class Something(
        x: Int,
        y: String
    )

    val someClass = new Something(1, "someString")

Is there a way I can refer to the parameters of a class using a string variable?  Something like the following?
val params = Seq("x", "y")

for (p <- params) println(someClass.`${p}`)

The actual class I'm referencing in production has at least 8 optional parameters.  A separate set of transformations need to be performed on all eight of these parameters.  Being able to refer to the parameter using a string variable would help out a lot.

No... Scala is strongly statically typed and you cannot expect it to automatically infer a type from a string.

Can you expand a bit more on the expected usage? Are all of the 8 parameters of the same type? Wouldn't a Map be a better representation of these data? Note that you can convert from a case class instance to a Map[String, Any] which may be good enough for your use case (losing type of the values).

This is plain Scala right? No Spark involved?

@GaëlJ you are correct a MapType might be a better option in this case.
However, the class is created upstream from my application by a third party vendor.  The class parameters have some proprietary data types that I can't share on this thread.
For now this is plain Scala.

Would a sequence of getter lambda-functions do?
val propertyGetters = Seq((i: Something) => i.x, (i: Something) => i.y)

for (propertyGetter <- propertyGetters) println(propertyGetter(someClass))
// 1
// "someString"


I think that might work.  Thanks so much.

Not that I recommend it as a general-purpose approach, but you can convert case classes to a Map pretty easily in scala:
val data: Map[String, Any] = (foo.productElementNames zip foo.productIterator).toMap

And then you can just params.flatMap(data.get).foreach(println)
